# How to implement a Best Score Today leaderboard using Game Center?

Tags: ios, ios7, game-center, gamekit, gkscore

I want to create a leaderboard in Game Center for the best scores submitted today, and I want it reset every day at midnight.

It's not hard to just create a "most recent score" leaderboard and keep track of the score for the day in the app and submit it, however my concern is that users who do not launch the app the next day will have an old score which remains in the "best score today" board until they launch it.

Is there any way to make scores expire, or only show the current scores for the day in a Game Center leaderboard?

Answer (score 1):

YOU need to do it in iTunes connect, there is ugode on Game center and leaderboards on this site: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/LeaderBoards/LeaderBoards.html

EDIT:
Here is explained time scope for GKLeaderboard
https://developer.apple.com/LIBRARY/IOS/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKLeaderboard_Ref/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: It looks like there's a timeScope property of GKLeaderboard. If that's the case, don't I need to set that in my app, not in iTunes Connect?

Comment: Trying to use the timeScope property in iOS7 gives me the following warning: "'leaderboardTimeScope' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 7.0 - GKGameCenterViewController no longer supports leaderboard time scopes. Will always default to GKLeaderboardTimeScopeAllTime."

Comment: It seems like I can use a GKLeaderboard object to pull all scores into an NSArray with a leaderboardTimeScope property set. This would be fine except then I need to design a custom view controller for displaying the scores. Is there any way to display the scores from a GKLeaderboard object in the default game center view controller (GKGameCenterViewController)?

Comment: You can use most recent score for now(in the itunes connect), I'm searching for other decision

Comment: I'm using that for now. My problem with that is let's say a user makes a high score, and then never logs in again. Then he will be the top scoring user forever or until somebody beats him, even months later. I want to have a best scores today list.