# Custom Score Challenges in Game Center

Tags: ios, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

Currently my app has a functioning leaderboard and I am trying to implement challenges but game center seems to only have challenges to "Beat my score" and that is really not that interesting. Is there any tutorials or information someone can give me to make custom challenges such as "First one to get 10,000pts" or "most points in a single day" ? Any help would be very appreciated. Thanks

Comment: The links on this question will help you understand setting up high score leaderboards by a time period: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20181488/how-to-implement-a-best-score-today-leaderboard-using-game-center

Comment: I am not really looking for leaderboards. I am trying to make more interesting challenges through game center unlike the challenges they currently have

Comment: You can make whatever challenges you want.  If I remember correctly, you can allocate up to 10,000 points for your game and something like 100 different challenges.  Just keep track of them within your app and whenever the user "Reaches 10,000 points" update that achievement to Game Center.

Comment: If you want the achievement to be unique and only achievable by one user of your app, like a "First person to ever score 10,000 points" achievement, you would need to track that in a database of some kind and update the database when someone has gotten the achievement, so it knows it cannot give that achievement out to anyone anymore.

Comment: I am not trying to do achievements, I am specifically trying to make challenges. Score challenges by default are sent by a user saying beat my current score. I don't think that is a very handy tool for my app and I want to see if it is possible to challenge people using game center like who can get more points in a day.

Comment: Read this link, its definitely possible.  Try googling for some solutions: http://www.addictivetips.com/ios/what-are-ios-6-game-center-challenges-how-do-you-send-them/

Answer (score 1):

What you want fits better to the Achievements design. Take a look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Achievements/Achievements.html).

And at the following link you can find some nice hints how to implement Achievements using Game Center: http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=10844